# Bootstrap 4 - Responsive Table Mobile, Exact Widths Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

Users can create custom tables and set column widths in percent that add up to 100.

The problem is that these set widths make cramped tables for mobile.

So my goal is for mobile that the table is scrollable horizontally with the bootstrap ‘table-responsive’ class.

I tried adding a class to the table columns for a mobile media query to overwrite the widths, but it just makes the table even more cramped.

```
//css
@media (max-width: 769px) {
    .wiki-table-c-width {
        width: auto !important;
    }
  }
```

```
//example table html 

<div class ="table-responsive">
    <table class ="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> <td class ="wiki-table-c-width" style ="width: 10%"></td> </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So basically set widths on desktop. (They can literally be anything, users choice) and auto width and scrollable horizontally on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `width` to `auto` it overwrites users given `width`s.
If you want to use their given `width`s, you should fix table's width on mobile screen.

```
@media (max-width: 769px) {
    table {
        width: 769px !important;
    }
}
```

Something like this, you'll be able to have a table with `width = 769px` on screens that is smaller than 769px. Also, user's given widths can be applied and user should scroll horizontally to see the whole table.